# Getting all lines from a file, and put unique lines in a new file

Tags: php, file

Using PHP I have tried all day to get this done. I failed. I want to:

1. open a directory and read all files there.
2. read each files contents line by line (each line is a name with no spaces (single column)).
3. put each line into a new file (newline by newline).
4. remove duplicate lines.
5. save the new file.

Easy for the gurus, mind numbing for me.

NOTE: Each file may be 500 lines long and 20 characters per line but, there is only around 20 files.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Thanks again.
Based on the posts below I tried

```
    $topdir = '/home/mycal25/public_html/processed/';


$files = glob($topdir."*.txt"); //matches all text files

$lines = array();
foreach($files as $file)
{
 $lines = array_merge($lines, file($file, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
}
$lines = array_unique($lines);

file_put_contents($topdir."all/all.txt", implode("\n", $lines));
```

But that did not work...
I tried a couple other variations to no avail..

Comment: Show your current code so we can help you to debug it.

Comment: I was so frustrated i deleted it. 8 hours of nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Something like:

```
$lines = array()
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $lines = array_merge($lines, file($file));
}

$lines = array_unique($lines);

$fp = fopen('dest.txt', 'w');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    fwrite($fp, $line);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Alternatively you could do this differently where you check for unique entries each time you load the new file. This would save on RAM but potentially use more CPU.

Based on your comment about opendir, you can do something like the following:

```
$files = glob('/home/mycal25/public_html/processed/*');
```

or sticking with [`opendir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php)

```
$topdir = '/home/mycal25/public_html/processed';
$dh = opendir($topdir);
while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
    $lines = array_merge($lines, file($topdir . '/' . $file));
}
```

I've skipped some vital error checking in places, just to make the code shorter and easier to read. But if you want to be sure, always check the return values from opendir/glob/fopen, etc

Comment: opendir('/home/mycal25/public_html/processed') or exit("Unable to open directory!")) {   ????

Comment: Would I open the directory this way then create the array?

Answer (score 0):

Just to point out, using `sort -u` on a unix-based system might help you out really easy if the sort order of the new file doesn't matter.

If you're running PHP on a host that's unix-based you can most likely use `sort` through [system()](http://php.net/system).

Answer (score 0):

8 hours wasn't for nothing; think like that and you'll definitely hate programming! I see a very good solution to the problem that might have a few bugs, but all the thinking and big strokes are there. You may just need some improvements on your methods of debugging.

Here's what I'd do: instead of inlining function calls write them out as their own statements and save their return values to meaningful variables. Check this out:

```
$topDir = '/home/mycal25/public_html/processed/';

/* Grab names of all needed text files */
$filePaths = glob($topdir . '*.txt');

$names = array();

foreach($filePaths as $filePath) {
    $fileLines = file($file, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    $names = array_merge($names, $fileLines);
}

$uniqueNames = array_unique($names);

$nameList = implode("\n", $uniqueNames);

file_put_contents($topDir . 'all/all.txt', $nameList);
```

That'd be my personal style. What you can do now is var_dump() every variable and run your script. By doing this you will eventually, by the output, find out which variable doesn't contain what you wanted it to contain.

Also, make sure that all error reporting has been enabled. Shameless plugging:  http://www.needtodevelop.com/error-reporting-in-php

Comment: Thank you. I tried this one too and still nothing. I will try again tomorrow. The one from Tim above worked but, it had to be in the same directory. I need to do this from a script in a lower directory. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: I didn't write the solution for you; I merely gave you a version that is slightly easier to debug.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$lines = array();

foreach($files as $file)
{
    $lines = array_merge($lines, array_fill_keys(file($file, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES), 1));
}

file_put_contents('file.txt', implode(array_keys($lines)));

?>
```